# Como desassociar essa string e Python?

Tags: python, string

Como eu posso quebrar essa string em Python e obter cada linha em uma variável?

String:

```
string = '''
          tipo-cliente
          Nome_da_Rede
          Senha_da_rede
         '''
```

como eu quero:

```
str1 = 'tipo-cliente'
str2 = 'Nome_da_Rede'
str3 = 'Senha_da_rede'
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é programar a solução.
Desta forma é possivel desenvolver um programa que resolva este problema utilizando as funções [split](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.split), [strip](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip) um comando condicional para decidir se uma variável possui um valor definido e um laço para iterar a string resultante da operação `split`.

Queremos quebrar uma string por um padrão, que vamos chamar de `token`, este token é a quebra de linha, representado por <kbd>\n</kbd>. Podemos ver este padrão apenas mostrando na tela o valor da variável string (em seu programa).

o resultado seria:

```
>>> string = '''
           tipo-cliente
           Nome_da_Rede
           Senha_da_rede
         '''
>>> string
>>> #'\n          tipo-cliente\n          Nome_da_Rede\n          Senha_da_rede\n         '
```

Repare que não estamos utilizando o `print` para exibir o valor da variável.

Fazendo o split pelo token \n temos o seguinte:

```
listanomes = string.split('\n')
```

Se verificar o retorno da função split, vai ver que ele vai retornar um array e o token que vai servir para "quebrar" a string será o `\n`.

Resultando em:

```
['', '          tipo-cliente', '          Nome_da_Rede', '          Senha_da_rede', '         ']
```

Agora basta só fazer o strip para que sejam removidos os espaços em branco, para que os valores do nosso array estejam da maneira que desejamos apresentar ao usuário:

```
for i in listanomes:
    item = i.strip()
    if item:
        print(item)
```

Agora que já possui os valores, pode armazenar da maneira que for mais conveniente.

O resultado final fica:

```
string = '''
          tipo-cliente
          Nome_da_Rede
          Senha_da_rede
         '''
string

listanomes  = string.split('\n')

for i in listanomes:
    item = i.strip()
    if item:
            print(item)
```

Comment: Ou mais sucintamente `listanomes = [item.strip() for item in string.split("\n") if item]`

Comment: Perfeito. Eu conhecia os métodos que me mostrou, más não sabia que eu podia quebrar usando o \n. Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 1):

Se o objetivo é transferir um número conhecido de linhas de texto de uma string para o igual número de variáveis:

- Quebre a string em linhas com a função [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) que retorna uma lista das linhas numa string, quebrando a mesma nas fronteiras de cada linha. *Veja a documentação da função para uma lista dos caracteres quebra de linha aceitos*
- Usando a função nativa [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) aplique a cada linha retornada por `str.splitlines()` a função [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) sem argumentos para que sejam removidos os espaços iniciais e finais de cada linha.
- Com a função nativa [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#filter), usando o argumento `None` como função de filtragem, remova as linhas vazias. `filter()` aplicado com argumento `None` remove todos os elementos de um iterável cujo o [valor testa falso](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) em python strings vazias em testes lógicos testam falso.
- De posse da linhas filtradas, apenas [faça o desempacotamento](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) dessas linhas nas respectivas variáveis.

```
texto = '''
          tipo-cliente
          Nome_da_Rede
          Senha_da_rede
         '''

linhas = map(str.strip, texto.splitlines())   #Quebra texto em suas linhas e remove os espaços iniciais e finais de cada linha.

s1, s2, s3 = filter(None, linhas)             #Remove as linhas vazias e as desempacotam em s1, s2, s3.

print(s1) #tipo-cliente
print(s2) #Nome_da_Rede
print(s3) #Senha_da_rede
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/RVlQcj)</sup>

> Evite usar o identificador `string` para variáveis pois a linguagem
> Python possui um módulo nativo chamado [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) e ao sobrescrever
> esse identificados poderá causar conflitos.